# The constructor Time is deprecated

Tags: java, time, deprecated

```
private static final Time BEGIN = new Time(9, 0, 0);
private static final Time END = new Time(20, 0, 0);
```

The constructor Time is deprecated, is there a way to fix these declarations?

Comment: The Time API tells you what to use instead.

Comment: Sure, create a calendar object with that time. You can't get around the date-part, but that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

You can now use as mentioned by javadocs.

```
Time(long time)
```

Constructs a Time object using a milliseconds time value.

Short search gave me this  :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

// set Date portion to January 1, 1970
cal.set( cal.YEAR, 1970 );
cal.set( cal.MONTH, cal.JANUARY );
cal.set( cal.DATE, 1 );

cal.set( cal.MILLISECOND, 0 );

java.sql.Time jsqlT = 
   new java.sql.Time( cal.getTime().getTime() );
```